# PhoneGap and cross domain calls

Tags: android, security, cordova, mobile

Ive been working on a security review for a client and came across this line in the config.xml
Its a phonegap app for android devices

```
<access origin=".*"/>
```

If it was only origin=* i would know it means it can access any other site.
but what does the .* mean? is it the same as *?

thanks

Comment: I would assume that this a regex expression, where `.*` means "match zero to N occurrences of any character".

Answer (score 1):

From Cordova Android [source code](https://raw.github.com/apache/cordova-android/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/Config.java):

```
private void _addWhiteListEntry(String origin, boolean subdomains) {
    try {
        // Unlimited access to network resources
        if (origin.compareTo("*") == 0) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "Unlimited access to network resources");
            this.whiteList.add(Pattern.compile(".*"));
        } else { // specific access
            // check if subdomains should be included
            // TODO: we should not add more domains if * has already been added
            if (subdomains) {
                // XXX making it stupid friendly for people who forget to include protocol/SSL
                if (origin.startsWith("http")) {
                    this.whiteList.add(Pattern.compile(origin.replaceFirst("https?://", "^https?://(.*\\.)?")));
                } else {
                    this.whiteList.add(Pattern.compile("^https?://(.*\\.)?" + origin));
                }
                LOG.d(TAG, "Origin to allow with subdomains: %s", origin);
            } else {
                // XXX making it stupid friendly for people who forget to include protocol/SSL
                if (origin.startsWith("http")) {
                    this.whiteList.add(Pattern.compile(origin.replaceFirst("https?://", "^https?://")));
                } else {
                    this.whiteList.add(Pattern.compile("^https?://" + origin));
                }
                LOG.d(TAG, "Origin to allow: %s", origin);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.d(TAG, "Failed to add origin %s", origin);
    }
}
```

So obviously they treat everything as regex if it's not exactly `*`. Probably not a good idea to trust in that behavior since it's not [documented](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) and not in the targeted [W3C Widget Access](http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets-access/) specification. (I think it's probably not even intended.)

However `.*` is still used in the PhoneGap 2.5.0 project template, so it's fine for now, as long as you stay with one version of PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is necessary:

http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets-access/

Not mentioned in the PhoneGap Docs:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Here is the Regex:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

```
".*" matches 
"def" "ghi" in 
abc "def" "ghi" jkl
```

Answer (score 0):

The *  means wildcard. When having the * present, it means that the app can access any external site. It you replace the * with a domain, then it will only allow the app to access that paricular site.

```
<access origin="*" /> // all external domains
<access origin="http://google.com" /> // app can only reach google all other doamins are restricted
```